# Laravel disable debug mode

Tags: laravel

How to disable debug mode in laravel?
I changed in .env file to APP_DEBUG=false still it is showing error message.
I checked in config/app.php also it is also having 'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', false)
Where else I need to change

Comment: clear cache and config `php artisan clear:cache && php artisan clear:config`

Comment: clear the cache and check as mentioned in the above comment. you can do all of above using `php artisan optimize`

Comment: Thanks it is working now

Answer (score 2):

run this command

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

and check again